# Is it possible to invite a guest user ID in Azure AD which doen't have email enabled

Tags: azure-active-directory

we have a scenario wherein we want to add a guest user to our Azure AD but that iser account doent have email configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to invite a guest user who doesn't have email configured.

Log in into Azure AD and select to resend the invitation to the user from their profile in the users section.

After re-sending the invitation, the invitation link is shown which he needs to provide to the guest user for accepting the invitation.

My blog : https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/05/13/inviting-guest-user-accounts-with-no-mail-enabled-to-an-azure-active-directory/
should help for much better understanding